# PHP form to disappear after submit

Tags: php

I am trying to see how I can get the page to confirm that it has been filled in.

this is what I have got.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{echo
        '<form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="From" name="from"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="sub"><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Message"name="mess"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>';}
else{
$to = 'test@test.com, '. $from=$_POST['from'];
$subject = $_POST['sub'];
$message = $_POST['mess'];

mail ( $to , $subject , $message);
    echo 'thanks for submitting!<br>';}

?>
```

Comment: What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: This code... my eyes...

Comment: What I want it to do is after someone fills the form out to make the form disappear and just tell them "thanks for submitting!"

Answer (score 0):

Replace Following code:

```
mail ( $to , $subject , $message);
    echo 'thanks for submitting!<br>';
```

By this:

```
if(@mail($to, $subject, $message)) {
  echo "thanks for submitting";
}else{
  echo "Unable to submit your email.";
}
```

For more info : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php 
Good luck!